# Check if table exists in hive metastore using Pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to check if a table exists in hive metastore if not, create the table. And if the table exists, append data.

I have a snippet of the code below:

```py
spark.catalog.setCurrentDatabase("db_name")
db_catalog = spark.catalog.listTables(dbName = 'table_name)
if any(table_name in row for row in db_catalog):
    add data
else:
    create table
```

However, I am getting an error.

```py
>>> ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined after inferring
```

I am unable to resolve the value error as I get the same errors for other databases' tables created in hive metastore. Is there another way to check if table exists in hive metastore?

Comment: use sql `create table if not exist`

Comment: BTW, have you missed a closing quote in the table_name in the code, or its a copy-paste mistake?

Comment: @JimTodd It's a copy paste mistake since it's only a snippet. The actual code was much longer.

Answer (score 32):

You can use JVM object for this.

```
if spark._jsparkSession.catalog().tableExists('db_name', 'tableName'):
  print("exist")
else:
  print("Not Exist")
```

Py4j socket used for Python functionality. Others operation uses JVM `SparkContext`.

In Spark Scala you can directly access.

```
spark.catalog.tableExists("dbName.tableName")
```

Comment: Nice, I like the direct boolean value resulting from this!

Answer (score 10):

As of 3.3.0:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Catalog.tableExists.html

```
spark.catalog.tableExists("my_table")
```

Comment: This answer works for a fully qualified table name too (spark.catalog.tableExists(<catalog-name>.<database-name>.<table-name>).

Answer (score 7):

In pyspark **2.4.0** you can use one of the two approaches to check if a table exists. Keep in mind that the Spark Session (`spark`) is already created.

```py
table_name = 'table_name'
db_name = None
```

1. Creating **SQL Context** from Spark Session's Context

```py
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sqlContext = SQLContext(spark.sparkContext)
table_names_in_db = sqlContext.tableNames(db_name)

table_exists = table_name in table_names_in_db
```

2. Using Spark Session **Catalog**

```py
tables_collection = spark.catalog.listTables(db_name)
table_names_in_db = [table.name for table in tables_collection]

table_exists = table_name in table_names_in_db
```

I would use the first approach because the second seems to trigger spark job, so it is slower.

In order to write or append a table you might use the following methods

```
df.write.mode('append').saveAsTable(table_name)
```

Answer (score 5):

try below:

```
table_list=spark.sql("""show tables in your_db""")
table_name=table_list.filter(table_list.tableName=="your_table").collect()
if len(table_name)>0:
    print("table found")
else:
    print("table not found")
```

Comment: `if len(table_name)>0:` can be simplified to `if table_name:`

Comment: If the database is default, use `spark.sql("show tables in default")`.

Answer (score 4):

The way I recommend is:

```
def check_table_exist(db_tbl_name):
    table_exist = False
    try:
        spark.read.table(db_tbl_name) # Check if spark can read the table
        table_exist = True        
    except:
        pass
    return table_exist 

check_table_exist(db_tbl_name="foodb.bar_tbl")
```

and use this bool flag in your script!

Answer (score 3):

Another suggestion avoiding to create a list-like structure:

```
if (spark.sql("show tables in <DATABASE>")
         .filter(col("tableName") == "<TABLENAME>")
         .count() > 0):
    print('found')   
else:
    print('not found')
```

Answer (score 3):

Combining the best of two answers:

```
tblList = sqlContext.tableNames("db_name")
if table_name in tblList:
    print("Table exists")
    # insert code to insert/append
else:
    print("Table does not Exist")
    # insert code to create
```

Hope that helps.

Brent

Answer (score 0):

We have used the following in databricks to check if a table exists, this should work I guess.

```
tblList = sqlContext.tableNames(<your db name>)
for tbl in tblList:
  if tbl == <table_name>:
    print("Table exists")
  else:
    print("Table doesnot exist, create the table")
```

Thanks

Yuva

Answer (score 0):

To check table exists in Databricks hive metastore using Pyspark. Use below code:

```
if spark.catalog._jcatalog.tableExists(f"{database_name}.{table_name}"):
  print("Table exists")
else:
  print("Table does not exists")
```